# How do I verify a json object loaded into a typescript class is correct?

Tags: json, typescript, validation, typechecking

I want to make sure the JSON I load to my typescript classes is valid.
Also, my classes have some logic, so I want want them to remain classes and not become interfaces.
I also need type checks and required/not required checks.
Right now I just load an object to my constructor and manually check each field.
Is there a way to do it by using the type information from typescript?
I tried looking at the generated javascript files but it's just javascript and the type information is already gone there.
Perhaps there's a way to use it in compile time? at that time, typescript knows the type.
I found a few libraries that do it, but none of them deals with the type of the property as well as required or not.

```js
class MyObject {
    constructor(json: any) {
        if (typeof json.id == 'number') {
            this.id = json.id;
        } else {
            throw new Error('ID is required');
        }
        if (json.name != undefined) {
            if (typeof json.name == 'string') {
                this.name = json.name;
            } else {
                throw new Error('Name exists, but it is not a string!');
            }
        }
    }
   id: number; // required
   name?: string; // optional
}

try {
    let m1: MyObject = {
        id: 123
    }; // works but m1 is not a class
    let isMyObject = m1 instanceof MyObject ? '' : 'not ';
    console.log(`m1 is ${isMyObject}instance of MyObject`);
    let m2 = new MyObject({
        "id": 123
    });
    let m3 = new MyObject({
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Mickey"
    });
    let m4 = new MyObject({
        // this will throw an error
    });
    console.log('OK!');
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.message);
}
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: If it's not a string it's not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Comment: @Andreas, ok than consider it a question about something like JSON.parse('{ "id" : 123 }'), which is the same thing as { "id" : 123 }.

Comment: Can anyone answer this? I can explore stuff if you have a lead. Right now I'm clueless on how to solve this without the manual checking I currently have.